# Basis of an implicitly given subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> $ \left\{ t\pmatrix{7 \\ -3 \\ 0 \\ 1}+s\pmatrix{7 \\ -5 \\ 1 \\ 0},s,t \in R \right\} \in R^4$
>
> Determine the basis of the subspace

I would say the basis is $ \pmatrix{7 \\ -3 \\ 0 \\ 1},\pmatrix{7 \\ -5 \\ 1 \\ 0}$
But I dont know what I should do with the parameters s,t?

Comment: It is not _the_ basis of this subspace, but it is _a_ basis of it.

Comment: Ok, so the parameters t and s can be ignored or set to s=1 and t=1. Is the approach different to explicitly given vectors?

Comment: @SuperNova No, those parameters are used to describe the set of all linear combinations of the two vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two vectors obviously span your subspace and since they are linearly independent they form a basis as well. (Note that "*the* basis" is bad wording, since there's more than one choice of a basis)

You don't do anything with the parameters $s$ and $t$. Consider
$$
V = \operatorname{span} \left\{ \pmatrix{1\\0} , \pmatrix{0\\1} \right\} = \left\{ s\,\pmatrix{1\\0} + t\, \pmatrix{0\\1} : s,t\in\mathbb R\right\} =  \mathbb R^2.
$$
The vectors $\pmatrix{1\\0}$ and $\pmatrix{0\\1}$ form a basis of $V=\mathbb R^2$, the parameters $s$ and $t$ are just used to describe the set of all linear combinations, the span.